# Convert mp3 into ogg?

Tags: audio

I using an audio player plugin to play mp3 and ogg files. But I'd want the editor to input only a mp3 file and it should automatically be converted into ogg file and send both files to the front-end.  Is there any WP function to convert mp3 files into ogg? 
I've seen some plugins that do that, but they have their own player. I just want the above functionality.

Comment: Please note that "wanting functionality" rarely makes good question in context of Stack Exchange. What have you tried? What did and didn't work for you? This is rather involved task, described in rather few words to expect people go and implement it from scratch for you.

Comment: @Rarst - I've seen that I can use `ffmpeg` to convert files, but I need to install this php extension. I wonder how do some plugins achieve this behavior without installing any PHP extension.

Answer (score -1):

this is not the answer you are looking for, but why not just allow users to upload or input both mp3 and ogg files, and have the player play both mp3 and ogg files?

Comment: This is what I have at this moment.